# Requirements to move to France as the spouse of a Spanish national

Tags: france

I am married with a Spanish national and having a resident permit of Spain (*tarjeta de residencia familiar de la union*) valid for five years. Now we both want to move to France, how can I change my residency in France to work and live and what are the requirements of France?

Answer (score 2):

As detailed in [Does a non-EU citizen residing in one EU country need to apply for a visa to move to another EU country for work?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/2971/does-a-non-eu-citizen-residing-in-one-eu-country-need-to-apply-for-a-visa-to-mov), you need to apply for a fresh residence permit. Your Spanish residence permit does not allow you to stay in France and there is no simple procedure to transfer it to another country. Fortunately, as an EU citizen's spouse, it should be relatively easy to get a residence permit in France.

Under EU law, if your spouse is making use of his or her right to free movement within the European Union, you are entitled to a residence card in France with minimal requirements and will have the right to work there as well. [The procedure is described on service-public.fr](http://vosdroits.service-public.fr/particuliers/F19315.xhtml) Mainly, you need to prove you are indeed in this situation by providing:

- Proof of your family link with your EU citizen spouse
- Proof that he or she is working or has sufficient resources

You also need to provide your passport and 3 photos of yourself. This residence card does not cost anything.

Note that some *préfectures* are notoriously understaffed and treat foreigners poorly (long wait, etc.). Once you have applied, you will however receive something called a *récépissé* that will allow you to stay for three months and must be renewed every three months until your application is processed.