# Non EU-husband wants to join EU-citizen wife in Germany, can he work?

Tags: working-visas, germany, eu-citizens, resident-permit, family

I have a question related to work permit in Germany.

Wife is a non-German EU citizen with residence registered in Germany. Her husband is non-EU citizen living outside Germany.

I know that he would be able to apply for a vise for joining families in order to come to Germany. Will that type of visa also automatically allow him to work in Germany, or he would be able only to live there?

Comment: Is your wife a German citizen, or is she a citzen of a different EU country? (The rules differ)

Comment: @Gagravarr his wife is non German EU citizen.

Comment: Note that in the duplicate question the EU citizen living in Germany is *working* there, not merely *registered*. If the wife mentioned in your answer is not working, she will have to prove she has sufficient resources to support the family. The husband would then have the right to work in Germany but without work or resources neither the EU citizen wife nor her non-EU husband have any unconditional right to reside in Germany. See http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/6056/us-citizen-with-eu-spouse-who-doesnt-yet-have-a-job/6057#6057 for more details on this distinction.