# Is Civic Integration exam needed for (non-EU) wife of Italian citizen to join him in the Netherlands?

Tags: netherlands, language-test, residence-cards

I'm an Italian citizen residing and working in the Netherlands. My wife is Brazilian. Does she need to pass a "Civic Integration exam" in order to join me in the Netherlands and apply for residence?

According to ind.nl, the procedure to obtain a ["residence permit" or "mvv"](https://ind.nl/EN/individuals/residence-wizard/family/marriage) requires such exam. But to obtain a ["certificate of lawful residence"](https://ind.nl/EN/individuals/residence-wizard/eu/third-country-nationals/) (which is specific for family members of EU citizens) no such requirement is mentioned.

As I understand, these are two alternate means for her to reside: one more general, another under EU "free movement" laws. Is this correct?

Is this exam really not necessary in our case then (if we take the "certificate of lawful residence" path)?

Answer (score 4):

Your understanding is correct, there are two routes and your wife would in fact receive a different document in each case, with the EU citizen family member status usually more advantageous in several ways. A civic integration course (or language test as is often required in other countries/situations) should not be required for your wife but you will need to prove that you, the sponsor, have the right to reside in the Netherlands under EU free movement rules (e.g. [that you have a job](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/6056/us-citizen-with-eu-spouse-who-doesnt-yet-have-a-job)).

Comment: Since many people do not understand the difference between e.g. and i.e., I will point out that having a job is one of a few possible ways a sponsor can have the right to reside in the country under the freedom of movement rules.

Comment: @phooh Thanks! I added a link to another question about this.